# Redux-react-hook requires <StoreContext.Provider>

Tags: reactjs, redux-react-hook

I get the following error in my react application

> Error: redux-react-hook requires your Redux store to be passed through
>   context via the

index.tsx:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <StoreContext.Provider value={store}>
        <App />
    </StoreContext.Provider>
</Provider>
```

User.tsx

```
const UserContainer = ({ insa }: { insa: string }) => {

const mapState = useCallback((state: StoreState) => user.find(s => s.name == name), [name]);
const site = useMappedState(mapState);
```

Comment: Do you have this resolved now?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the react-redux Provider tag?

Like this:

```
<StoreContext.Provider value={store}>
    <App />
</StoreContext.Provider>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your answer.